# Creating a concurrent collection which does not load data in memory from Stream : Java

Tags: java, file, java-stream, etl

I have a requirement to send each line from a Huge file to a Java Collection,Iterator,Iterable. From this collection,iterator etc an existing framework takes the data and loads into a processing system. However the requirement is to send a **Concurrent** Collection,iterator etc to this framework, this is the part i am facing difficulty.

I have a **java.util.stream** which i got from a huge file.
There are numerous lines in the file, i want to pass all the lines into a java **Concurrent java.lang.Iterable** or a **Concurrent java.util.Iterator** or a **Concurrent java.util.Collection** which does not store all the records in the memory so that i do not get Exceptions like **OutOfMemory** etc.,

- I was able to get a Iterator implementation from the java Stream but
  it is not **Concurrent**

. Any idea on how to make a Concurrent implementation with or without using the Stream API will will be much appreciated.

Comment: Why not use `Supplier` class which allows you to lazy-load the data?

Comment: You should be precise. Does the framework mandate `Collection`,`Iterator`, `Iterable` or do you have a choice? Since there is no such thing as a “concurrent iterator”, that would eliminate the requirement. Likewise, an `Iterable` would allow to create distinct iterators which can be used concurrently, but as long as they are read-only, that would still work with any collection.

Comment: @Holger The framework mandate Collection,Iterator, Iterable only. I will try Iterable, however can you suggest any links for the same

Comment: @Dummy i will check on Supplier Class

Comment: You didn’t provide a clarification. You named again **three** different types, together with the word **only**. So what does it mean? Can you choose either of these three types or does the framework mandate a type?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I can choose either of these three types

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a “Concurrent Iterator”.

While there are Concurrent *Collections*, the `Iterator`s created for them are *weakly consistent* (which describes their behavior regarding updates of the underlying `Collection`) and a single `Iterator` instance can only be used by a one thread at a time.

Since the `Iterator` from a `Stream` created via `Files.lines` has no underlying `Collection` that could get updated and doesn’t support the `remove()` operation, it can’t exhibit any behavior that would contradict the behavior of an `Iterator` created for a Concurrent Collection, apparently expected by the framework¹. Well, except that it doesn’t support the `remove` operation, but I have the feeling that this is not an issue for your desired operation.

So if the framework offers you the option to pass an `Iterator` to it, you might use it to pass the `Iterator` created via `Stream.iterator()`. As long as the `Stream` doesn’t have either of the stateful intermediate operations `sort` or `distinct`, it will exhibit the desired lazy behavior.

---

¹ Most notably, it will never throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`.